# What metrics are useful for measuring developer progress based on git?

Tags: git, metrics, code-metrics, developer-tools

Can `git` show any metrics that might be helpful to track the progress of developers?

I know `git shortlog --since="1/1/12"` as a basic utility to see how many total commits each developer has. What about lines per commit or files added?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "progress"?

Comment: Anything really... just want to get a handle on the development process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another service called [Codegraphite](http://www.codegraphite.com/) which also tracks lines, commits,files, and images added or removed in a repository. It works with any git repo as far as I can tell.

It also visualizes all that data into pages of charts and graphs. It has some interesting ones that can compare coders against each other and a commit stream. For some those metrics might not be useful, but it does provide a way to set a benchmark. It also lets you keep track of everything going on in your code with one snap shot.

Comment: I would encourage you to read [this site's policy on self promotion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/253560). [It appears you are affiliated with Codegraphite](https://www.elance.com/s/afont1991/resume/), so you need to disclose that affiliation in your answers that promote the product to avoid running afoul of this site's spam policy.

Answer (score 1):

There is [GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/), a utility that will analyze a repository and output some statistics and metrics.

Unfortunately, although it’s written in Python, it’s quite unix-dependent (for no real reason) and the statistics are odd when you want it to look at other branches than just master. I’ve been wanting to write a tool myself for a long while, but never really got around to it.

That being said, GitStats will still work good enough and the data it is able to generate is nice too. You can find some examples [here](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/).